# Two models for one view, displaying the view as empty

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a question, i have 2 tabs and have corresponding VOs, in both tab, there is a link summary that will display the data from both VO (summary is readonly screen, no inputs required).

In my controller i have placed a method as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/summaryProduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewProductSummary() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("basicDetailsProduct", productVO
                .getBasicDetailsProductVO());
        model.put("additionalDetailsProduct", productVO
                .getAdditionalDetailsProductVO());
        return new ModelAndView("SummaryProduct", "model", model);
    }
```

But in summary screen, fields remain null. summary.jsp

```
<label class="formHeading">${model.basicDetailsProduct.prodDesc}</label>
```

ProductVO has both screen's VO and all are in session in spring-servlet.xml.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since *model* is a `Map`, try to access it using the brace notation

```
<label class="formHeading">${model['basicDetailsProduct'].prodDesc}</label>
```

Comment: The summary page needs to just display whatever we input data in 2 screens and display it in new tab. Please let me know if my understanding is correct with below:

I will need to do a form submit so controller method has to be RequestMethod.POST
2. A link will always cause a get request
3. So now submitting the form, so its working with even ${model.basicDetailsProduct.prodDesc}, but its opening in same tab even though written as target="_blank"

Please suggest